# How can I skip a few characters while reading an input file with Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

How can I skip a few characters while reading an input file with Scanner?
I have this input file which has some numbers before the actual string and I can't remove those numbers because they are important too. I need to store them in another integer array:

```
3 onion pepper olive
3 mushroom tomato basil
3 chicken mushroom pepper
3 tomato mushroom basil
2 chicken basil
```

Can I skip the integers and read the Strings first, and then read the integers second?
Here is all the code I 've been working on:

```java
        import java.util.*;
        import java.io.*;
        public  class Pizza {
            public static int numofpizzas;
            public static Scanner input;
            public static String[][] pizzaIng;
            public static File file;
            public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
                // assigning the file object
                file = new File("an example");
                // setting up the scanner
                input = new Scanner(file);
                // reading and storing the input file data
                pizzaIng = new String[][]{{input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()} 
                {input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()}};
                for (String[] i: pizzaIng) {
                    for (String j: i) {
                        System.out.println(j);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You seem to have edited a solution (Answer) into your Question. That's not how the site works. Kindly revert the edit, so it's a Question. If you want to post a solution, please do that in an Answer. If the code you edited in gave you an error, then it's unrelated to this particular Question. If you get an error because your input is unlike what you posted, then that is also a new Question. Note that you should never invalidate any Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first character of a string by using the subString() method. Using .subString(1) will just skip the first character of the String (in your case the integer) and .subString(2) will skip first two characters (in your case the integer and the space).

The new code would look like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public  class Pizza {
    public static int numofpizzas;
    public static Scanner input;
    public static String[][] pizzaIng;
    public static File file;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // assigning the file object
        File file = new File("testText.txt");
        // setting up the scanner
        input = new Scanner(file);
        // reading and storing the input file data
        pizzaIng = new String[][]{{input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()},
                {input.nextLine()},{input.nextLine()}};

        for (String[] i: pizzaIng) {
            for (String j: i) {
                System.out.println(j.substring(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I run the Code it's giving me a StringIndexOutodBoundsExeption

Comment: how can I fix that

Comment: I suppose that is because you are trying to make a substring of an empty string? So make sure that all the strings in your pizzaIng are actually filled and that there are no empty strings in there

Comment: To test this you can first do `System.out.println(j);` before the `System.out.println(j.substring(2));`

Comment: When I print out the Strings they are all normal

Comment: but it still gives me the StringOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @abhinavbandaru have you exactly copied the code I suggested? And what does it mention about the line where the exception occurred?

Comment: I did a little editing to the code which I will edit into the Question

Comment: @abhinavbandaru when I run your newly edited code it returns an InputMismatchException

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229164/discussion-between-abhinav-bandaru-and-jens-van-groeningen).

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches for this, but it all depends on the data. Here are two of the few possible approaches,

1. Obtain a new substring that only contains the item name.

You may use this approach if the pattern mentioned in your examples are consistent and the quantity is always less than 10 so that the starting index of the item name is fixed. So in the last for loop in your code snippet, you could do the following,

```java
for (String j: i) {
    int startingIndex = 2
    j = j.substring(startingIndex)
}
```

Yet, the con is if the quantity exceeds 9 or more, then the starting index changes and as a result your substring will miss the first character.

2. Replace (delete the) numeric characters using regex pattern.

In this case even if the quantity exceeds one digit (10 and more), the numbers will be removed and the item will be retained.

```java
for (String j: i) {
    String pattern = "[0-9]"
    j = j.replaceAll(pattern, "")
}
```

However, if the item name contains numbers, then they will also be replaced. So that's the con of this approach. To overcome this, the following regex can be used, where the regex only

```java
for (String j: i) {
    String pattern = "([0-9]+)([A-Za-z\s0-9]+)"
    j = j.replaceAll(pattern, "$2")
}
```

This regex dissects parts of the strings into 2 parts: the quantity represented by "([0-9]+)" and the item name represented by "([A-Za-z\s0-9]+)" where we accept alphanumerics and whitespaces for the item name. Then in the following line, the entire string is replaced by "$2" where "$2" represents the item name. So only the item name (which might include numbers) are retained. The quantity part of the string is removed.

Hope this helps you :) If it does, i would very much appreciate if you would mark my answer as "Accepted". Good day!

Comment: Thanks! but What does the Regex pattern mean?

Comment: @abhinavbandaru Regex is short for "regular expression". A regex is a pattern. By giving the string.replaceAll method a regex, you can tell the replaceAll method to replace all characters in a string that match the regex. The regex i have given, which is [0-9] tells to simply match a number and replace all numbers with "" which is to delete it.

Comment: You should remove the meta commentary in your post about accepting your Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since "the number in front is important too", why not create a class for the whole line to begin with?

```
class Ingredient {
 // add getters and setters for those
 int amount;
 String name;
}
```

Then you can create one of those ingredients for each line. Since that is your original question, maybe you can use

```
static Pattern ingredientPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+) (.*)");
public static Ingredient fromLine(String line) {
 Ingredient result = new Ingredient();
 Matcher matcher = ingredientPattern.matcher(line);
 if (matcher.matches()) {
  result.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
  result.setName(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
 } // else throw exception or something
 return result;
}
```

The pattern is a regular expression with two groups, the first one containing the numbers ("[0-9]+", the + meaning "1 or more"), and the second the rest of the string.

And you should be able to parse the whole thing with

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
 ingredients.add(fromLine(sc.nextLine()));
}
```

or, for a given filename

```
List<Ingredient> ingredients = 
 Files.lines(filename)
  .map(MyClass::fromLine)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```